# C++ & Qt: Random string from an array area

Tags: c++, arrays, string, qt, random

In my small Qt application, I want to pick a random string out of an array after I clicked on a button. I've read many threads but nothing works for me.

So in my slot there's an array with several strings in it. I also implemented `<string>, <time.h>` and srand.

```
#include "smashrandom.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

SmashRandom::SmashRandom(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    // shortened version
    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(Randomizer()));
}

void SmashRandom::Randomizer()
{

    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    std::string characters[6] = {"Mario", "Luigi", "Peach", "Yoshi", "Pac Man", "Sonic"};
}
```

But how can *I* pick a random **string** out of my array "characters"? Normally I use rand()% for int or double arrays, but in this case I don't know how to use it for random strings.

In addition to that, it is possible to select a random string from an area inside the array? For example I just want want a random string from Mario to Yoshi so Pac Man and Sonic can't even show up?

I hope you can understand my problem and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The C++ standard now discourages using rand/srand in C++ code. It's not exactly related to your question, but consider using the <random> header instead

Comment: Or use qrand() in a Qt app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`random`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) header.

```
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution dist(0, 5);
int StringIndex = dist(generator);

std::string ChosenString = characters[StringIndex];
```

The above will generate a random index into your array.

If you want to limit the range, change the constructor of `dist`, for example (`dist(0,2)` would only allow for Mario, Luigi and Peach to be selected, Indexes 0 1 and 2).